# About integration limits over region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to integrate $f(x,y)=y^2-2x^2y+6x^3-3xy+2y-6x$ over $\{y\geq 2x^2-2, y\leq 3x\}$

[image]

Im in doubt if it can be computed in just "one step" as:

$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\int_{2x^2-2}^{3x}f(x,y)dydx$

**EDIT:**
I fail to verify this on Mathematica:

```
Integrate[(y^2 - 2 x^2 y + 6 x^3 - 3*x*y + 2 y - 6 x) Boole[    y >= 2*x^2 - 2 && y <= 3*x], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}] = -5.81287
```

Is not equal to:

```
Integrate[(y^2 - 2 x^2 y + 6 x^3 - 3*x*y + 2 y - 6) , {x, -1/2,    2}, {y, 2 x^2 - 2, 3 x}] = -13.6254
```

Comment: yes it can be done like this

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam Please, see my edit.